# How to convert time to AM/PM in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm working with a pandas series. Datetime object that I created in this format:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_nyc = pd.read_csv('project.csv')
raw_nyc['pickup_datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(raw_nyc['pickup_datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Example of one entry in this format: 2010-04-15 20:58:29+00:00

I'm hoping to use the time within this object to create a new column that would output AM or PM. Ideally I would even break it down more. Something like AM, PM, evening and night. I am unsure how I can do this efficiently. Thank you!

Comment: posted a solution, does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks Naveed it worked. I'm still a beginner so and this makes me realize I need to go over strftime again to fully understand it.

Comment: there is always something we all have to learn. Im glad it worked for you. so,   Stackoverflow synonym for thanks is accepting the answer, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh that's very good to know. Just did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
%p return you the AM or PM of the time

pd.to_datetime(raw_nyc['pickup_datetime']).dt.strftime('%p')
```

```
data_time = {'DateTime':['2019-01-01 12:32:39-04:00','2019-01-01 00:34:52-04:00','2019-01-01 21:01:02-04:00','2019-01-01 01:05:10-04:00','2019-01-01 01:01:11-04:00'],
            }
df=pd.DataFrame(data_time)

df['AM/PM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.strftime('%p')

                     DateTime   AM/PM
0   2019-01-01 12:32:39-04:00   PM
1   2019-01-01 00:34:52-04:00   AM
2   2019-01-01 21:01:02-04:00   PM
3   2019-01-01 01:05:10-04:00   AM
4   2019-01-01 01:01:11-04:00   AM
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), you can format a date with `%p` to extract AM/PM.

| Directive | Meaning | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| %p | Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. | AM, PM (en_US) |

So if I understand correctly your expected output, use [**`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and [**`pandas.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
raw_nyc['pickup_datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(raw_nyc['pickup_datetime'])

dico = {'AM': 'midnight to noon', 'PM': 'noon to midnight'}

raw_nyc['Col1'] = raw_nyc['pickup_datetime'].dt.strftime('%p')
raw_nyc['Col2'] = raw_nyc['pickup_datetime'].dt.strftime('%p').map(dico)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(raw_nyc)

            pickup_datetime Col1              Col2
0 2010-04-15 20:58:29+00:00   PM  noon to midnight
```

Comment: Same as my answer except the mapping part